# Crystal Report Viewer Print to Default Printer Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that I've imported into the form, and I want it so that when I double click on something, it will load the report, and then print it.

Is there a way to do that through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [PrintToPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on the report.

> Prints the specified pages of the report to the printer selected using the PrintOptions.PrinterName property. **If no printer is selected, the default printer specified in the report will be used.**

Something like this:

```
using (var report = new YourCrystalReport())
{
    // Call report.SetDataSource() if necessary
    // Call report.SetParameterValue() as necessary

    report.PrintToPrinter(...);
}
```

Although the doc I linked says VS2003, I just tried it in VS2012 using the latest crystal driver, and the call appears to be the same.